# Keycloak group policy update - UI does not reflect the change

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm making a keycloak extension (on kc 23.0.4/quarkus) in which I have to rename a group policy.
My code seems to work fine as the change is persisted in keycloak db but the UI does not reflect the change.

Here's my code

```java
public void editGroupsAndPolicies(RealmModel realm, KeycloakSession session, AuthenticationManager.AuthResult auth, SubcontractorEditRequestDTO dto) {
        if (!hasRole(session, realm, "manage-subcontractor")) {
            throw ErrorResponse.error("User has no permission", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        // retrieve parents
        GroupModel driversGroupModel = session.groups().getGroupByName(realm, null, "Drivers");
        GroupModel fleetManagersGroupModel = session.groups().getGroupByName(realm, null, "FleetManagers");

        // retrieve subgroups to edit
        GroupModel driversSubGroup = session.groups().getGroupByName(realm, driversGroupModel, dto.oldName());
        GroupModel fleetManagerSubGroup = session.groups().getGroupByName(realm, fleetManagersGroupModel, dto.oldName());

        driversSubGroup.setName(dto.newName());
        fleetManagerSubGroup.setName(dto.newName());

        String oldPolicyName = "isFleetManagerOf" + dto.oldName();
        String newPolicyName = "isFleetManagerOf" + dto.newName();
        ClientModel clientModel = realm.getClientByClientId("realm-management");

        ResourceServer resourceServer = session.getProvider(StoreFactory.class).getResourceServerStore().findByClient(clientModel);
        PolicyStore policyStore = session.getProvider(StoreFactory.class).getPolicyStore();

        AuthorizationProvider authz = session.getProvider(AuthorizationProvider.class);
        
        
        Policy policyToBeEdited = policyStore.findByName(resourceServer, oldPolicyName);
        AbstractPolicyRepresentation representation = ModelToRepresentation.toRepresentation(policyToBeEdited, authz);
        representation.setName(newPolicyName);
        representation.setId(policyToBeEdited.getId());

        RepresentationToModel.toModel(representation, authz, policyToBeEdited);


        AdminAuth adminAuth = new AdminAuth(realm, auth.getToken(), auth.getUser(), auth.getClient());
        AdminEventBuilder adminEvent = new AdminEventBuilder(realm, adminAuth, session, session.getContext().getConnection());
        session.getTransactionManager().commit();
        adminEvent.operation(OperationType.UPDATE).resourcePath(authz.getKeycloakSession().getContext().getUri()).representation(representation).success();
    }
```

It looks like some kind of server caching issue, I also tried forcing cache invalidation by moving a subgroup

```java
realm.moveGroup(driversSubGroup, driversSubGroup);
```

but it doesn't work.
Keycloak doesn't log any error.

I tried to invalidate cache from bash and it works,

```bash
./kcadm.sh create clear-realm-cache -r MyRealm -s realm=MyRealm
```

but I need to do it via java code

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's a definitive solution but I managed to solve in this way:

```java
Cache<String, Revisioned> cache = session.getProvider(InfinispanConnectionProvider.class).getCache(InfinispanConnectionProvider.REALM_CACHE_NAME);
Cache<String, Long> revisions = session.getProvider(InfinispanConnectionProvider.class).getCache(InfinispanConnectionProvider.REALM_REVISIONS_CACHE_NAME);
RealmCacheManager realmCacheManager = new RealmCacheManager(cache, revisions);

RealmCacheSession realmCacheSession = new RealmCacheSession(realmCacheManager, session);
realmCacheSession.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using:

```
session.getProvider(StoreFactory.class)
```

for loading Authz resources, use

```
authz.getStoreFactory()
```

instead and the cache will be invalidated.

Here are a few more things to point out regarding the code snippet:

1. It is not necessary to use `ModelToRepresentation`/`RepresentationToModel` at all. All changes can be done on the Model object (in your case `policyToBeEdited.setName(newPolicyName)`) and everything will be updated in DB.
2. Never use `session.getTransactionManager().commit();`. This way all changes that are done after this line are invalid as Keycloak does not create a new transaction.
3. Cleaning up caches should not be necessary if it is, it is suspicious and it is rather an issue in Keycloak so it is worth reporting such things.